# Custom instrumentation for abstract generic class in .NET

Tags: c#, quartz.net, newrelic

Using Quartz.Net running as windows service to schedule import jobs.
Want to track transactions for these jobs using NewRelic.

Note: method is async so enabled async in `newRelic.config`

```
<configuration xmlns="urn:newrelic-config" agentEnabled="true">
    ...
    <appSettings>
        <add key="AsyncMode" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Also: `JobBase` is **generic** and **abstract**

Consider the following class:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Castle.Core.Logging;
using Quartz;

namespace XXX.Scheduler.Job
{
    public abstract class JobBase<TResult>
    {
        public async void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
          // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Added following custom instrumentation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension xmlns="urn:newrelic-extension">
  <instrumentation>

  <tracerFactory name="NewRelic.Providers.Wrapper.CustomInstrumentationAsync.OtherTransactionWrapperAsync" metricName="Category/JobBaseAsync" transactionNamingPriority="7">
      <match assemblyName="XXX.Scheduler" className="XXX.Scheduler.Job.JobBase">
        <exactMethodMatcher methodName="Execute" />
      </match>
    </tracerFactory>

  </instrumentation>
</extension>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't generate any transactions in NewRelic.

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25554810/custom-instrumentation-for-generic-classes-in-net-using-newrelic) tracing a generic class should be fine.
Not sure If the TracerFactory works with abstract classes though.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? If yes, please, share your soltion, because I have this same one :/

Comment: Based on [this docs](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/instrumentation/net-custom-instrumentation) there is no way to fetch async non-iis data.